# How do I remove the inside borders of a series of images and keep the outside border continuous in css?

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a series of images that I want have border around. I don't want borders in between the images but when I set borders of the middle images to 0, I get a gap between the top borders .

So something like this, with many images in the middle.

```
 _____
|_____|
```

I've tried setting the padding, but since my images take different shapes, I can't have so many special cases for each shape.

How do I remove the gaps but still keep a single continuous border around a shape of images.

Edit: I'm trying to make a game where if a person selects a picture, it highlights all the ones similiar to that around it. Something like bejeweled, where if you highlight a colour, the same colour tiles highlight themselves. Images are all the same size, layed out in a grid pattern.

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/CFjfk/

Answer (score 2):

Remove *all* borders from the images and wrap them in a `<div />`:

```
<div class="image-wrapper">
  <img />
  <img />
  ...
  <img />
</div>
```

Then just apply CSS to it:

```
.image-wrapper {
  border: 8px solid rgb(220, 220, 255);
}
```